# Setting a custom header on the server-side, and retrieve its value using JavaScript on the client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-headers

Is it possible to set a custom header as part of a GET response from the server-side, and retrieve its value using JavaScript/JQuery on the client side once the response is received?

If so, what is the proper way of doing this in JavaScript?

Comment: No, you can't. It would be a security vulnerability. Hence, you can only do it at server-side. Why would you need something like that?

Comment: If you're talking about an ajax request, you can use http://stackoverflow.com/a/4881836/1331430

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, the answer is no, not directly.

If you really need to do this, as a workaround you can push values as hidden fields if returning HTML, part of your response if returning JSON etc.

If you absolutely, unavoidably need to do this, you can make a separate HEAD XMLHTTPRequest to the desired page, and load the headers from there.

See [Http headers in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215613/http-headers-in-javascript)